# How to combine multiple methods without repeating queries in Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method `index`

```
protected function index(Request $request)
{
    $articles = Article::published()->paginate(8);

    return view('pages.blog', [
        'articles'    => $articles,
        'orientation' => $this->getOrientation(),
        $this->getCategory($request)
    ]);
}
```

And a method `getCategory()`

```
public function getCategory($request)
{
    if ($request->has('category')){

        $search = $request->get('category');

        $articles = Article::published()
            ->where('orientation', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->paginate(8);

        return view('pages.blog', [
           'articles' => $articles,
            'orientation' => $this->getOrientation()
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to get my `getCategory` function outside of my index function.

It works, only, with my debug bar, I have all the SQL queries (those of index and those of `getCategory`).

- Is it possible to optimize my code? Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: What is exactly that you are asking? I'm not a Laravel pro, but you are calling one method that returns a view with a multidimensional array (index > view(blog)), and from that array you call another method that also returns a view with identical variable names (getCategory > view(blog))? So you are showing the same view twice?

Comment: Yes, I believe. In fact, I just want to try to recover the categories but I'm afraid to put everything in the index method, so I get confused. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need both results add cache for query in index and get full result from cache.

Or if you have all results maybe use collections filter for same your collection from index and provide display data what you need.

For example `getCategory` add param where you set your collection from index. In article add filter to get only data what you are interest in.

Comment: Use this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter
this is peudo code


`function index(){
$articles = Articles::published()->paginate(8);
$this->getCategory($articles);
}`

`function getCategory($list){
$articles = $list->filter(function($value){
//your conditions from request
})->all();
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm nowhere near an editor to chekc this, but here goes. First function:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
$articles = Article::published()->paginate(8);

return view('pages.blog', [
    'articles'    => $articles,
    'orientation' => $this->getOrientation(),
     //$this->getCategory($request) - this i don't think can work like this. You are calling
     //a function that does not return a value, but instead loads a view, insted:
    'categories' => $this->getCategory($request)//the idea here is you call a function and 
     //get a return as an array
]);
}
```

Second function:

```
public function getCategory($request)
{
if ($request->has('category')){

    $search = $request->get('category');

    $articles = Article::published()
        ->where('orientation', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->paginate(8);

    $result = [
    'articles' => $articles,
    'orientation' => $this->getOrientation() 
];
}
 else $result = null;
 return $result;
}
```

This might work, once again, im a noob. But i don't see why you need 2 methods for this since there is a `if ($request->has('category')){` which will yield a `null`. Idk, give it a try...